# IntelliJ, Spring Boot & jdbm connection/run time issue

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Having an issue that I have been trying to solve for hours now.

I am creating a Java app, using the Spring Boot framework on IntelliJ. I am trying to connect to a local database and have gotten to the point where when I run the programme it perpetually runs without a runtime error.

Here is the code and syntax I am using:

```java
String databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://device-name:port-number;Database=JavaProject;IntegratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);
```

I was having a previous issue where I was getting the errors:

- com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.;
- Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-12.4.2.x64

I hoped I'd solved this by placing the "mssql-jdbc_auth-12.4.2.x64" file in Java\jdk-20\bin , but this could still be a contributing factor, I'm not sure.

Please help me as I've been troubleshooting this for about 2.5 hrs.

TIA

Comment: I have a development.  I have opened up my database and the test I created has been inputted it but the programme is still running - what do i not know here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to close the connection. This is why my programme ran continuously.